# Geometric phase and energy eigenstates in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, adiabatic, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In the section "*Geometric phase*" in the text "*Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*" by Griffiths page 379, he states $\psi_{n}(t)$ depends on $t$ because there is some parameter $R(t)$ in the Hamiltonian that is changing with time, then we have $$\frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial R}\frac{d R}{d t}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ so that the geometric phase is $$\gamma_{n}(t) = i \int_{0}^{t} \bigg \langle \psi_n 
\bigg| \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial R} \bigg \rangle\frac{dR}{d t'}dt'~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$ How is equation (1) derived, in the sense that in order to use the chain rule you should be able to write the time dependence of $\psi_n$ as $\psi_n(\cdot, R(t))$.

Also, is there a basic example of what $R(t)$ would be for some specific Hamiltonian just to get an idea of how this is applied?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Equation (1) is just the chain rule of differentiation. What about it do you find confusing?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty To use the chain rule we assume we can write $\psi_n(\cdot, \cdot, \cdot, R(t))$ which implies $\frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial R}\frac{d R}{d t}$, I'm not sure how to show that we can write $\psi$ in this form. But I think it probably follows from $\psi_n(t) = e^{-(\frac{i}{\hbar})\int_{0}^{t} dt' H((t'))} \psi_n(0)$ if $R(t)$ is some parameter of the Hamiltonian. Actually I'm not sure if that makes sense...What do you think?